# Factor $f(x) = x^5 - 2x^4 - x^3 + 2x^2 -2x + 4 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ into a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I need help in the problem factor a polynomial into a product of irreducible polynomials.

> **Problem:** Factor this polynomial $f(x) = x^5 - 2x^4 - x^3 + 2x^2 -2x + 4 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ into a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

- Over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have
  $$f(x)=(x-2)(x^2-2)(x^2+1)$$
- Over $\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}$ we have
  $$f(x)=(x-2)(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})(x^2+1)$$
- Over $\mathbb{C}$ we have
  $$f(x)=(x-2)(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})(x-i)(x+i)$$

Can you show that each of the factors is irreducible over the respective field?

Comment: Just show that each of these polynomials is irreducible?

Comment: @Minh Yes, e.g. $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ using Eisenstein's criterion for $p=2$.

Comment: This is my opinion. We have factored $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$, hence $f(x)$ is reducible.

Comment: @Minh I meant do you know if $x-2$, $x^2-2$, $x^2+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so on?

Comment: Oh!! I see. I’m going to prove these polynomials are irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your polynomial is equal to $$ \left( x-2 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}-2 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+1
 \right) 
$$

Comment: i.e. $f(x) = (x-2)(x^2-2)(x^2+1)$, but I see three polynomials not irreducible in $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$.